# Add external geojson to leaflet layer

Tags: ajax, leaflet, geojson

I am new to leaflet and JavaScript. I was thinking I could use geocommons and GeoJSON to host data for a mapping project.

I found [External GeoJSON and Leaflet: The Other Way(s)](http://lyzidiamond.com/posts/external-geojson-and-leaflet-the-other-way). This tutorial on reading external GeoJSON using a leaflet plugin but I haven't been able to get it to get the points to render on my map. The map portion of the code renders fine but the GeoJSON  won't appear.

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://geocommons.com/datasets/168923/features.json?lat=53.796&amp;lon=-1.551&amp;radius=3&amp;callback=?", {onEachFeature:popUp});

function popUp(feature, layer) {
  layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
}

geojsonLayer.addTo(myMap);
```

Comment: Can you please open the html file you created in your preferred browser and add what errors you might be seeing in your JavaScript console? Here is some [further documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to help you diagnose the bug.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the information on debugging. I am getting three errors.

Comment: Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax/master/dist/leaflet.ajax.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. index.html:1
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the [leaflet.ajax plugin](https://raw.github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax/master/dist/leaflet.ajax.min.js) as `leaflet.ajax.min.js` in the same folder as your html page, then call it by adding this line in between the `<head>` tags

```
<script src="leaflet.ajax.min"></script>
```