# Issues with adding external GeoJSON into Leaflet

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I've tried adding my GeoJSON file onto my map using jQuery and AJAX (the different ways shown [here](http://lyzidiamond.com/posts/external-geojson-and-leaflet-the-other-way/)). My map renders but the features don't show up.

One version of my code:

After reading through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485723/add-external-geojson-to-leaflet-layer) I saved the leaflet.ajax plugin as      `leaflet.ajax.min.js` in the same folder as my html page, then called it by adding this line in between the  tags:

```
<script src="leaflet.ajax.min" type=text/javascript""></script>
```

Then I have this:

```
  var save41 = L.GeoJSON.AJAX("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sidewalkballet/TTCriders/develop/save41.geojson", {onEachFeature:popUp});

  function popUp(feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
      }

  save41.addTo(map);
```

The errors I get in Chrome are:

"GET file:///localpath/leaflet.ajax.min net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" (though it is in the same folder as my HTML)
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" (referring to the l.GeoJSON.AJAX bit)

Advice? Am I not reaching for the GeoJSON file correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you run a local server at the parents folder of the Leaflet folder?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple problems.

1. Your `leaflet.ajax.min` import request is not finding that file on your local system.  If `leaflet.ajax.min` is indeed on your local file system, make sure the path in the `script` tag is relative to your webserver root directory (where your `index.html` file resides).
2. Once you fix issue #1, you are going to have a problem accessing the geojson from github (see [my answer to a similar question on gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94113/using-geojson-hosted-on-github-from-leaflet-it-doesnt-work)).  The easiest solution to this problem is to copy the contents of the geojson into a local file and access it that way.

Comment: Thanks sfletche. I have it in my local file system and this is the path I have in the `script` tag: `src="/Users/<localpath>/leaflet.ajax.min" type="text/javascript"`. I'm still getting the error.

Comment: rather than use a root level absolute path in the `src` attribute, use a relative path from your webserver root directory (relative to where your `index.html` file sits)

Comment: When I just have `<script src="leaflet.ajax.min" type="text/javascript"></script>` it's still not found.

Comment: I swapped out the local file for `<script src="https://raw.github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax/master/dist/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>` and I don't get any errors for it anymore. Now working on other errors! Thanks.

Comment: @sidewalkballet - is your leaflet.ajax.min file in the same directory as your index.html?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same folder.

Comment: are you running a local server when doing the ajax call?